# Is it possible to express this sum in a closed form?

Tags: summation, closed-form

Consider the sum
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac1{2^n+3^n},$$
which clearly converges (by comparison with $\sum\frac1{2^n}$, say), and Mathematica approximates the limit to be $0.821354$.

Is there any way to write this in a closed form?

Comment: Good question. If instead of $2$, $3$ we take the golden ratio and its negative inverse, we end up with the reciprocal fibonacci constant, for which no closed form exists. This makes it unlikely that a closed form exists in this case, but still not impossible.

Comment: "... the reciprocal fibonacci constant, for which no closed form exists. ..." This is not proved. You should say "no closed form is known"

Comment: Is there any reason that you suspect that this sum **should** have a closed form?

Comment: This is of the form $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n\,\text{sech}(nx)$. According to [Dieckman's tables](http://www-elsa.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/InfProd/InfProd.html#SeriesxofxHyperbolicxFunctions), even with $a=1$ it involves hypergeometric functions.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom None really, only the fact that is a naturally arising question given the very familiar limit of $\sum\frac{1}{2^n}$.

Comment: @jjagmath You're right of course, my claim was too bold. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

The closest thing I've found so far, with reference to [Dieckman's tables](http://www-elsa.physik.uni-bonn.de/~dieckman/InfProd/InfProd.html#SeriesxofxHyperbolicxFunctions), is that
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{2^n+3^n} &=\frac12\sum_{n=0}^\infty\big(\tfrac1{\sqrt6}\big)^n\operatorname{sech}(\tfrac n2\log\tfrac32)\\[5pt]
    &=\frac12\,{_2\phi_1}(\tfrac23,-1;-\tfrac23;\tfrac23;\tfrac13),
\end{align*}
where $_r\phi_s(a;b;q;z)$ is the [basic hypergeometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_hypergeometric_series).